# Get ID of affected document by using update()

Tags: mongodb, meteor, mongodb-query

I'm using this for doing an upsert:

```
Articles.update(
    { title: title },
    { 
        title: title,
        parent: type
    },
    { upsert: true }, 
    function(res) {
        return console.log(res);
    }
);

console.log(needToGetID);
```

Now I need to get the _id of the document which has been updated or inserted. I thought I can get that via callback, but `res` is undefined.
I assume there is just one unique document which is defined by the query.

**Update**

Forgot to mention that I'm using meteor...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The intent of [`.update()`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.update) is to basically just "update" the matching document(s) ( as "multi" can also be applied here ) and be done with it, therefore that especially considering this "could" be applied to multiple documents then returning such information would not really make sense in the terms of that operation.

However if your intent is to modifiy a single "specific docucment", then the [`.findOneAndUpdate()`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.findOneAndUpdate) method would apply assuming you are using mongoose:

```js
Articles.findOneAndUpdate(
    { title: title },
    {
        title: title,
        parent: type
    },
    { upsert: true, new: true  }, 
    function(res) {
        return console.log(res);
    }
);
```

Also note the `new: true` which is important, as without it the default behavior is to return the document "before" it was modified by the statement.

At any rate, as the return here is the document that is matched and modified, then the `_id` and any other value is present in the response.

---

With meteor you can add a [plugin](https://github.com/fongandrew/meteor-find-and-modify) to enable `.findAndModify()` which is the root method:

```js
meteor add fongandrew:find-and-modify
```

And then in code:

```js
Articles.findAndModify(
    {
        "query": { title: title },
        "update": {
            title: title,
            parent: type
        },
        "upsert": true, 
        "new": true  
    }, 
    function(res) {
        return console.log(res);
    }
);
```

Note that you should also really be using the [**`$set`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/set/) operator, as without it the changes basically "overwrite" the target document:

```js
Articles.findAndModify(
    {
        "query": { "title": title },
        "update": {
            "$set": {
                "parent": type
            }
        },
        "upsert": true, 
        "new": true  
    }, 
    function(res) {
        return console.log(res);
    }
);
```

Comment: Thanks. That's great. But I think `findOneAndUpdate` is not available in meteor, is it?

Comment: @user3848987 Not clear in your question which API you were using. `.findAndModify()` should be available, with a similar syntax. At least it is accessible on the "server" side if not minimongo, albeit from a raw access. But you can always use meteor methods to wrap.

Comment: "findAndModify, aggregate functions, and map/reduce aren't supported" :-( So I guess I have to do an update and then a findOne with the same query...

Comment: @user3848987 But you can add a [plugin](https://github.com/fongandrew/meteor-find-and-modify). And the same applies to `.aggregate()` etc. Which as I already state are always available from "raw" driver access anyway. Point is this is how you get the affected document details.

Comment: @user3848987 There, even added example usage. Probably the most useful thing you have seem all day. You also have the privileage to "upvote" here, so that would be nice.

Comment: @BlakesSeven Any other alternate to that specific plugin you mentioned because it isn't actively maintained and we can't take risk on using some third party unmaintained plugin for db communication.